# Deleting instantiated objects outside of a function?

Tags: c++

How do you delete an instantiated object inside a function then delete when another function is called?

For example:

```
int function_test(){
    object* a = new object();
}

int function_test2(){
    delete a;
}
```

Object a needs to be deleted when function_test2() is called. Function_test() creates and sets the value of object a.

Comment: You cannot delete the object without a reference. You pass the reference back. You take a lot of care of documenting that `function_test2()` must be called to cleanup each `function_test()` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete something, you need a pointer to something.

When you allocate an object in function `function_test` and want to delete it in `function_test2` you need to take care of a way for `function_test2` to get a hold of the pointer to the object you wish to delete.

There are multiple ways of doing that, but the most common one is for `function_test` to return the pointer to the caller, and then passing that pointer to `function_test2`:

```
object* function_test() {
    object* a = new object();
    ...
    return a;
}

void function_test2(object* a) {
    ...
    delete a;
}
```

The caller would need to "transfer" the pointer, like this:

```
object obj = function_test();
...
function_test2(obj);
```

Other ways of transferring the pointer are using file-static pointers, using global pointers, and using instance variables when functions `function_test` and `function_test2` are member functions of a class.

Comment: Function a creates and sets the value of object a. I need a to be deleted when another function is called.

Comment: @Akito In your code `a` is local to `function_test`. There is no way to get to it once `function_test` is over - in your code it becomes a memory leak.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to solve. I have to instantiate Object a and delete it when function_test2 is called, which then calls function_test and then recreates object a. I know it creates a memory leak. Which is why I'm trying to find a solution to this.

Comment: @Akito The only solution is to pass that pointer to outside the function in one way or the other. There is no solution that lets `a` remain a local object.

Comment: I have tried making Object a pointer outside of the function but makes an error while doing so.

Comment: @Akito Declare it `object* a;` outside the function; set it inside the function `a = new object();`

Comment: @Akito: Does memory allocation have anything to do with this problem at all? Would your problem be different if you needed to "transfer" a simple `int` from one function to another?

Comment: Object a will have a different value whenever function_test is called. But the previous values won't be removed from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer local variables between functions. If you like to do something like this, I suggest you return the pointer, so you can pass it to the next function.

```
object *function_test()
{
auto *o = new object{};
return o;
}
```

however, this has as disadvantage that you have to capture this variable everywhere where you call it and have to to do memory management. Most likely you just want to use something object oriented, similar to:

```
class ObjectOwner final
{
public:
     int function_test(){
         a = new object();
     }

    int function_test2(){
         delete a;
     }
private:
   object *a{nullptr};
};
```

which can be used as:

```
 ObjectOwner owner;
 owner.function_test();
 owner.function_test2();
```

Even better would be using a `std::unique_ptr<object>` so that when you forget to call the 2nd function, the memory is freed.

Finally, you can consider using a constructor/destructor.

```
class ObjectOwner final
{
public:
     ObjectOwner()
         : a(std::make_unique<object>())
     {
     }

    ~ObjectOwner() = default;
    void func() { /*Do something with a*/ }
private:
   std::unique_ptr<object> a{};
};
```

Allowing you to write:

```
ObjectOwner owner{};
owner.func();
```